# Is IAR compatible with Win10

Tags: iar

I try to install IAR for version:EWSTM8-2203. After the installation, when I try to run the unpacker, it says that:

The license for "STM8.EW.LIBSRC" "1.04" did not have a value for the variable 
  "PASS"

My OS is Win10. Is Win10 compatible to IAR?

Comment: I think your best bet is to contact IAR support.

Comment: IAR is compatible with Windows 10 32/64-bit since I am using it right now but I am using the EWARM (for ARM architecture) version...But, did you have any license key to install the extended source library for your target STM platform?

Comment: Probably you need to update your license to use the latest version of IAR-EWSTM8 from their licensing website.